# ASP.NET MVC 3 membership with MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

How would I go about implementing membership in an ASP.NET MVC 3 site that uses MySQL as the database?

I'm not 100% familiar with membership provider and if I can even use it in this instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consult [this article](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/). One of the things it covers is setting up and configuring a MYSQL membership provider that comes with the official MySQL .NET connector. It works OK, I've used it on several projects. Here is the [official article.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check these options ? You will have to do some  tweaks by considering @Anže Vodovnik's solution.

https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit

http://netrsc.blogspot.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-membership-management.html