# asp.net - register and login using mssql database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Simple question - is there any tutorials how to implement registration and login on asp.net mvc3 webpage using mssql database? And how to check user authorization (is logged or not and his privileges)?

Greetings

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3 membership with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709767/asp-net-mvc-3-membership-with-mysql)

Comment: The default Membership Provider uses MS SQL Server.  In Visual Studio you can create an MVC3 Internet Application and take a look at everything it's doing.  The only "black box" is the provider implementation (though I think that's open source too), but if you Google things like "custom MVC3 membership provider" then you'll find a lot of information for writing your own, probably including some tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do that much as the heavy lifting is done by the membership provider - that is to say that all the controls and code as such are DB agnostic and don't really care which data storage mechanism you use. All you should need is to install MySQL Connector and change the configuration settings in Web.Config to point to the MySQL provider rather than the out of the box MSSQL provider - you should find what you need here:

http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/